# How can I create a python dictionary from unstructured text?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a set of broken link checker results that exist in a text file:

```
Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/
├───OK─── http://www.this.com/
├───OK─── http://www.is.com/
├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/
├───OK─── http://www.set.com/
├───OK─── http://www.one.com/
5 links found. 0 excluded. 1 broken.

Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/
├───OK─── http://www.this.com/
├───OK─── http://www.is.com/
├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/
3 links found. 0 excluded. 1 broken.

Getting links from: https://www.boo.com/
├───OK─── http://www.this.com/
├───OK─── http://www.is.com/
2 links found. 0 excluded. 0 broken.
```

I'm trying to write a script that reads in the file and creates a list of dictionaries with each root link as the key, and its children as the values (including the summary line).

The output I am trying to achieve looks like this:

```
{"Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/": ["├───OK─── http://www.this.com/", "├───OK─── http://www.is.com/", "├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/", "├───OK─── http://www.set.com/", "├───OK─── http://www.one.com/", "5 links found. 0 excluded. 1 broken."], 
"Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/": ["├───OK─── http://www.this.com/", "├───OK─── http://www.is.com/", "├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/", "3 links found. 0 excluded. 1 broken."],
"Getting links from: https://www.boo.com/": ["├───OK─── http://www.this.com/", "├───OK─── http://www.is.com/", "2 links found. 0 excluded. 0 broken."] }
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
result_list = []

with open('link_checker_result.txt', 'r') as f:
    temp_list = f.readlines()
    for line in temp_list:
        result_list.append(line)
```

Which gives me the output:

```
['Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/', '├───OK─── http://www.this.com/', '├───OK─── http://www.is.com/', '├─BROKEN─ http://www.broken.com/', '├───OK─── http://www.set.com/', '├───OK─── http://www.one.com/', '5 links found. 0 excluded. 1 broken.', 'Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/', '├───OK─── http://www.this.com/', '├───OK─── http://www.is.com/', '...'  ]
```

I recognize there are some features that each of these sets share, for instance, a blank line in between, or the fact that they start with "Getting...". Is this something I should try splitting on before writing to a dictionary?

I'm new-ish to Python, so I admit I'm not even sure if I am going in the right direction. Would really appreciate some expert eyes on this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand how this is _unstructured_. There's a header, there are lines of data that start with `├─`, and there's the summary, which _doesn't_ start with `├─`. How can this be more structured?

Comment: Are you able to modify the code that produces the text file? It would be more straightforward to load the data into a dictionary within that code, rather than from an artifact of that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be quite short actually, within 4 lines of code:

```
finalDict = {}
with open('link_checker_result.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = list(map(lambda line: line.split('\n'),f.read().split('\n\n')))
    finalDict = dict((elem[0],elem[1:]) for elem in lines)
print(finalDict)
```

Output:

```
{'Getting links from: https://www.foo.com/': ['+---OK--- http://www.this.com/', '+---OK--- http://www.is.com/', '+-BROKEN- http://www.broken.com/', '+---OK--- http://www.set.com/', '+---OK--- http://www.one.com/'], 'Getting links from: https://www.bar.com/': ['+---OK--- http://www.this.com/', '+---OK--- http://www.is.com/', '+-BROKEN- http://www.broken.com/'], 'Getting links from: https://www.boo.com/': ['+---OK--- http://www.this.com/', '+---OK--- http://www.is.com/']}
```

What the above code does is, reading the input file and splitting it using two consecutive newline `\n` characters in order to get the links for each url.

Finally it creates tuples of the first element and the rest of each list and transforms them into key-value pairs in the `finalDict` dictionary.

An easier to comprehend way is the one below:

```
finalDict = {}
with open('link_checker_result.txt', 'r') as f:
    # Getting data and splitting in order to get each url and its links as a unique list element.
    data = f.read().split('\n\n')
    # Splitting each of the above created elements and discarding the last one which is redundant.
    links = [line.split('\n') for line in data]
    # Transforming these elements into key-value pairs and inserting them in the dictionary.
    finalDict = dict((elem[0],elem[1:]) for elem in links)
print(finalDict)
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you comrade!

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the result you want:

```
result = {}

with open('link_checker_result.txt', 'r') as f:
    temp_list = f.readlines()
    key = ''
    value = []
    for line in temp_list:
        if not line:
            result[key] = value
            key = ''
            value = []
        elif not key:
            key = line
        else:
            value.append(line)

    if key:
      result[key] = value
```